# Regex match for numbers,letters,space and underscore does not work in PHP

Tags: php, regex

1. `if(preg_match("^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$^",'name'))` -> 1
2. `if(preg_match("^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$^",'name--'))` -> 1 //should be a zero. works in js but php

1st scenario it's fine. but in the 2nd scenario I want it to be a zero but preg_match outputs 1. This regex works in js as I want. What's wrong with PHP code I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` quantifier matches zero characters in the class `[A-Za-z0-9 _]` followed by the end of the input. The result should not be surprising; the regex works "as intended".

Adding a start of input anchor makes the match fail as expected:

```
preg_match("^\\^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$^",'name--')
```

And of course it might be better to use the classic `/` delimiter because using `^` (which, as a delimiter, will go at the *start* of the regex) is IMHO asking for trouble:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/",'name--')
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `^` as delimiter, what is ... not so good, because it is the start-anchor too. Thus you have no start anchor, which means, that `*` covers exactly 0 characters, what is valid.

```
~^[a-z0-9 _]*$~i
```